# Expression involving square roots not simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a relatively simple expression here that is not simplifying:

$$
\frac{2 s_0 \left(\sqrt{\gamma ^5 s_0}+\sqrt{\gamma ^9 s_0}\right)+\sqrt{\gamma ^3
   s_0}+2 \sqrt{\gamma ^7 s_0}+\sqrt{\gamma ^{11} s_0}+\sqrt{\gamma ^7 s_0^5}}{\gamma 
   \left(\gamma ^2+\gamma  s_0+1\right){}^2}
$$

```
$Assumptions = {(s0 | γ) ∈ Reals, γ > 0, s0 > 0};
(Sqrt[s0 γ^3] + 2 Sqrt[s0 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7] +
   Sqrt[s0 γ^11] + 2 s0 (Sqrt[s0 γ^5] + Sqrt[s0 γ^9]))/(γ (1 + 
    s0 γ + γ^2)^2) // Simplify

(Sqrt[s0 γ^3] + 2 Sqrt[s0 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0 γ^11] + 
   2 s0 (Sqrt[s0 γ^5] + Sqrt[s0 γ^9]))/(γ (1 + 
     s0 γ + γ^2)^2) == Sqrt[s0 γ] // Simplify
```

The output is:

```
(Sqrt[s0 γ^3] + 2 Sqrt[s0 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0 γ^11] + 
 2 s0 (Sqrt[s0 γ^5] + Sqrt[s0 γ^9]))/(γ (1 + s0 γ + γ^2)^2)

True
```

Why is Mathematica not simplifying to this much simpler form $\sqrt{s_0 \gamma}$? I think my assumptions should be enough. I can do the simplification by hand

Comment: `Assuming[{γ>0,s0>0},(Sqrt[s0 γ^3]+2 Sqrt[s0 γ^7]+Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7]+Sqrt[s0 γ^11]+2 s0 (Sqrt[s0 γ^5]+Sqrt[s0 γ^9]))/(γ (1+s0 γ+γ^2)^2)//Refine//Simplify]`

Comment: @chyanog why do I need refine as well as simplify?

Comment: From the documentation of `Sqrt`: `Sqrt[z^2]` is not automatically converted to `z`. (And then they recommend the usage of `PowerExpand` for positive, real `z`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 expr = (Sqrt[s γ^3] + 2 Sqrt[s γ^7] + Sqrt[s^5 γ^7] + Sqrt[s γ^11] + 
        2 s (Sqrt[s γ^5] + Sqrt[s γ^9]))/(γ (1 + s γ + γ^2)^2);


Simplify[PowerExpand[expr]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why this is needed though

Comment: @JoeBentley Mathematica needs `PowerExpand` to open up the radicals. I guess this is by design.

Comment: @Nasser:  Presumably because you don't want Mathematica doing things like $\sqrt{(-1)(-2)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-2}$ by default.

Answer (score 4):

More by way of explanation of the "indifference" that causes `Simplify` to not budge.  In order to factor the expression so that it can be reduced, all the square-roots have to be factored and initially the complexity (computed by `` Simplify`SimplifyCount ``, which is equivalent to `LeafCount` on these examples) remains the same:

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7]]
Simplify`SimplifyCount[s0^(5/2) γ^(7/2)]
```

> ```
> (*
>   11
>   11
> *)
> ```

The actual algorithm used by `Simplify` is unknown (to me), but it makes sense to reject a transformation that results in an expression with the same complexity as measured by the `ComplexityFunction` (to avoid getting stuck in an infinite cycle of equivalent-complexity expressions).

While there is a simpler solution (see @Nasser's), another approach is to tweak `ComplexityFunction` to make the desired steps seem "simpler":

```
cf = LeafCount[#] + 2 Count[#, Power[_Times, _], {0, ∞}] &; 
Simplify[(Sqrt[s0 γ^3] + 2 Sqrt[s0 γ^7] +
   Sqrt[s0^5 γ^7] + Sqrt[s0 γ^11] + 
    2 s0 (Sqrt[s0 γ^5] + Sqrt[s0 γ^9]))/(γ (1 + s0 γ + γ^2)^2),
 γ > 0 && s0 > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf]

(*  Sqrt[s0 γ]  *)
```

Raise the coefficient of `Count[]` in `cf` to `5` and the result will be `Sqrt[s0] Sqrt[γ]`.